# How to read data by line and return a dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, readline

read data from line by line,

```
for line in sys.stdin:

    print(line)
```

the each line input is following:

New York 100
Orlando 200
LA 300
D.C. 400

the output I want is a dataframe:

```
         city     value
    0  New York    100
    1   Orlando    200
    2        LA    300
    3      D.C.    400
```

the way I am doing is read the line and save all lines as a list of list, where each line content is a list

```
list_of_lists = []
for line in sys.stdin:
        new_list = [elem for elem in line.split()]
        list_of_lists.append(new_list)
```

and then convert this list_of_lists to a DataFrame.

I feel this way is pretty stupid, so I am wondering if there is any other way.
Thanks.

Comment: i do not want to print each line out, instead I want to convert it to a dataframe

Comment: Yes, well, what exactly have you tried? Have you looked at the pandas documentation for creating DataFrames? what exactly is your question?

Comment: Append to a list, and then join by newline, and pass to StringIO.

Comment: see my updated editing, I tried using a list-of-list, and convert list of list to dataframe. feel this is not a smart way.

Comment: it's going to be tricky, because you don't have a clear separator... If values are separated using different separator compared to the Cities, containing multiple words like `New Yourk` or `san benedetto val di sambro
De`, then please specify that separator in your question

Comment: yep, this is another my question. if I separate by space, the first line gonna to split as ['New', 'York', 100]. I do not know how to avoid this. Would you mind give me a hint what separator should I use?

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys, re, pandas as pd

data = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()   # obtaining the list of lines from stdin
data = [re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+$)', l) for l in data]  # split each line into 2 items: `city` and `value`
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['city','value'])   # constructing dataframe

print(df)
```

The output:

```
       city value
0  New York   100
1   Orlando   200
2        LA   300
3      D.C.   400
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.rsplit` to split from the right side and only one time

```
list_of_lists = []
for line in sys.stdin:
        new_list = line.rsplit(1)
        list_of_lists.append(new_list)
```

Or, put into a pandas series first

```
import sys, re, pandas as pd

data = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()

pd.Series(data, name='A').str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
```